# What am I doing wrong in calculating OR?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, coefficients

I am calculating odds ratios over several subsets of a population. Here is one subset:

[image: Distribution of the levels of exposure over my dichotomous outcome.]

"Normal" and "0" are the reference groups. "Dibirads" is the outcome and "BMIcat" are the levels of exposure. I will also attach the code I used to calculate beta coefficients and Odds Ratios

[image: here]

However, the results show as follows:

[image: ORs and CI]

If you calculate them mathematically, they aren't matching with the R output. Is something wrong with my code? The Beta coefficients still match up with the Odds Ratios so something is wrong there as well.

Comment: Hi you might want to provide an reproducible example in the question.

Comment: What were the odds ratios that you got when you calculated them separately/manually? How did you account for the covariate "BMIAvg" in your mathematical calculation? It will help to see your mathematical formula and what were the differences between your OR.